# TypeScript: Asserting correct this context for a set of imported methods

Tags: typescript

I have class with many methods (~200), which to declutter I've moved to an object on the class, and the actual method definitions to a series of different files.  In order to maintain the correct this context, I import all these methods and bind them accordingly, however TypeScript complains.

```
The 'this' context of type 'typeof import("./methods")' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Main'.
  Type 'typeof import("/methods")' is missing the following properties from type 'Main': name, methods
```

Example:

```
// index.ts
import * as methods from './methods';

export default class Main {
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  name: string;

  methods = (Object.keys(methods) as Array<keyof typeof methods>).reduce((acc, k) => {
    acc[k] = methods[k].bind(this);
    return acc;
  }, {} as typeof methods);
}

const inst = new Main('Anga');
inst.methods.DoSomething();
```

```
// methods.ts
import Main from '.';

export function DoSomething(this: Main) {
  console.log(this.name);
}

export function DoSomethingElse(this: Main, input: string) {
  console.log(`${this.name}: ${input}`);
}
```

How can I assert that the this context does in fact match after binding?